# After upgrade to Kali 16.02, ACPI Error: No handler for region [ECOR]....

Tags: kali-linux

I have recently upgraded my Kali rolling 16.02 to the latest version and I started having a problem with the booting displays, so usually it displays the hard drive size, but recently it started displaying this:

```
ACPI Error: No handler for region [ECOR]....
ACPI Error: Region Embedded Control...
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed......AE_NOT_Exist
ACPI Error: No handler for region [ECRM]....
```

etc

How should I deal with these errors?